# How to auto increment for a coulmn in sql server limited to partition

Tags: sql, sql-server, auto-increment, database-partitioning

For auto increment for a column, we use IDENTITY in SQL Server.

**Syntax**

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
EmployeeID INT IDENTITY,
Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
.
.
)
```

The default starting value of IDENTITY is 1 and will increment by 1 for each record.

The problem that I see with this logic is that it will generate across the table but I am interested in auto-increment per partition.

I can use counter in order to auto-increment per partition but the issue I see with counter is that suppose as part of single query I have to insert multiple rows into a table. Then I have to execute the same query two times. 
1.  Calculate the no. of rows to insert for the counter. 
2.  Insert the data.

So, what is the right way for auto-increment within the partition?

Comment: For anything more interesting than `IDENTITY` that still needs to be transactional, [sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql) are your friend. Specifically, multiple rows are a job for [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql).

Comment: If you know the field(s) you partition function is based on you could always create a view and throw in a ROW_NUMBER()  based on the partition function fields. I don't know how that would add up performance wise and may not be suitable.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, when you said 'partition' are you talking about table partitioning. If so the partition key doesn't have to be the identity key. Could you clarify what you are trying to accomplish, add data examples of the partition you are inquiring about?

Comment: @Random_User - It sounds like he would like to use some type of IDENTITY within an Aligned index over a partitioned table.